# Configure WebCodecs API video decoder to match an NVENC Encoder

Tags: encoding, decoding, video-encoding, nvenc, webcodecs

I have an H264 NVENC Encoder setup which encodes a video stream. I want to decode frames of that stream using the WebCodecs API in Google Chrome.

My decoder configuration setup looks like this:

```
  let decoderConfig = {codec: "avc1.428020", width: 480, height: 270};
  decoderConfig.description = new Uint8Array(dataFromEncoder);
  decoder.configure(decoderConfig);
```

Where `dataFromEncoder` is an the following array obtained from the [NVENC NvEncGetSequenceParams](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__ENCODE__FUNC.html#gac92c3a7554ccea0a45954b9ded492139) function: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 100, 0, 50, 172, 43, 64, 240, 71, 245, 128, 136, 0, 0, 31, 64, 0, 21, 249, 4, 32, 0, 0, 0, 1, 104, 206, 60, 176]`

When I run the setup I get the error: `Failed to execute 'configure' on 'VideoDecoder': Failed to parse avcC.`

From what I understand from the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webcodecs-avc-codec-registration/#videodecoderconfig-description) the error refers to the `dataFromEncoder` being wrong in some way.

What am I missing? Am I using the correct NVENC function?

I have considered my codec string (`avc1.428020`), I am not sure if it corresponds to my encoder. The `428020` part is described in [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551340/understanding-avc-codecs-avc1-42c020-vs-avc1-428020) and [this doc](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/video/H264-SVC), but I have yet to find the corresponding information in the NVENC H264 docs. Is this sub-string even relevant, and if so how do i get it from the NVENC encoder?